# Getting NaN loss with padded sequences containing masked numpy.inf with Keras LSTM network

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, sequence

I am working on a project in which I need to train an LSTM network to predict a next-in-sequence coordinate-tuple. I enhance my training dataset of sequences of coordinate tuples (trajectories), by taking the first n tuples in a trajectory, and then padding the rest, then taking the first n+1 tuples, padding the rest, and so on. My problem is that if I pad with np.inf, I get Mean Squared Error loss of nan, which must mean that these np.inf values, even though they are masked by a Masking layer, are still taken into account for the loss calculation. I can, of course, change the pad-value, but since the loss of NaN confirms that the pad-value is taken into account for loss calculation, I must be doing something else wrong as well. I expect it to not be taken into loss-calculation since it should be ignored through masking with mask_value=np.inf. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance!

Code below:

**Pad_sequences call**

```
padded_values = np.squeeze(tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(train_sequences, maxlen= 3177, padding='post',dtype=float, value=np.inf))
```

**Raw Input**

```
array([[-0.1843775,  0.6867699],
       [-1.0841161, -3.0429556],
       [ 1.3582058, -0.6040352],
       [ 1.8754534, -1.7010269],
       [-1.5366333, -2.2335546],
       [ 1.9193598, -0.285654 ]], dtype=float32)
```

**Padded input**

```
array([[-0.18437751,  0.6867699 ],
       [-1.0841161 , -3.04295564],
       [ 1.3582058 , -0.6040352 ],
       ...,
       [        inf,         inf],
       [        inf,         inf],
       [        inf,         inf]])
```

**Tuple in finished dataset (padded input, label)**

```
(array([[-0.18437751,  0.6867699 ],
       [-1.0841161 , -3.04295564],
       [ 1.3582058 , -0.6040352 ],
       ...,
       [        inf,         inf],
       [        inf,         inf],
       [        inf,         inf]]), array([[2.154067, 0.871821]], dtype=float32))
```

**Creating tf.Dataset**

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    padded_generator_whole_trajectory,
    output_types= (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes= ((3177,2),(1,2))
)
train_data = train_data.batch(10)
spec = train_data.element_spec
```

**Model (Keras)**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(type_spec=spec[0]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=np.inf))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Comment: Note that `np.inf*0` is `NaN`.

Comment: But is that how masking works? It's just multiplied by 0? Because 0 would also mess with the loss calculation, right?